# How to run gprolog on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, prolog, homebrew, gnu-prolog

I have just installed gnu-prolog using `brew install gnu-prolog`. When I try to run `gprolog` in the terminal I get `gprolog: command not found`. I tried doing the same to my other machine that is running ElCapitan and all worked perfectly.

Is there a way for me to get `gprolog`to work for macOS Sierra?

Comment: It works for me macOS Siera (10.12.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your Homebrew installation. But you can also install GNU Prolog using MacPorts or by downloading its Mac OS X installer from its website.

Comment: Hi, yes brew did not like me having an old Xcode and the Xcode-beta simultaneously. I discovered that by simply running 'brew doctor' in terminal.  I then removed Xcode and set the path to Xcode-beta as brew suggested.

Comment: Just a remark regarding your mention of MacPorts: Right now (2016 Sep 25) MacPorts cannot install gprolog on Sierra because it depends on "apple-gcc42", which currently is not supported for Sierra. No idea if there's an easy fix, I'm not very familiar with the mechanics of MacPorts.

Answer (score 1):

For the ones using MacPorts - you may download an installation package of  gnu prolog directly from its site. It used to solve older installations issues and I have found it to solve the current one as well

use the link

http://www.gprolog.org/gprolog-1.4.4.pkg.zip

best

yehuda

Comment: Hey, I downloaded it, but it still doesn't work, and gives me the same error as above.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, the standard GNU Prolog installation package puts Prolog in the `/opt/local/bin` directory, which isn't normally in your path.

After installing the GNU Prolog package, open Terminal and type this command:

```
open -t ~/.bashrc
```

At the bottom of that file add this line:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:$PATH"
```

then save & close the editor. Then type this command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This reloads all the commands in the `.bashrc` file into your current Terminal session. The next time you open Terminal you won't have to do that.

Now you should be able to start GNU Prolog by typing this command:

```
gprolog
```

The output should look like this:

```
GNU Prolog 1.5.0 (64 bits)
Compiled Jul  8 2021, 23:55:41 with /usr/bin/clang
Copyright (C) 1999-2021 Daniel Diaz

| ?-
```